# paypal notify_url not working and tx ID variable not pass to thank you page

Tags: php, paypal

Here is my paypal buy now html code:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="alex@xumanii.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Bewolf Shooping Cart">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo $grandtotal2;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="<? echo $info['member_id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.bewolfclothing.com/thankyou.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.bewolfclothing.com/notify_paypal2.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.bewolfclothing.com/mycart.php">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0">
<div class="submit-container"><input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="CHECK OUT" /></div>
</form>
```

In my paypal account, under profile, my selling tools, I have set the AUTO RETURN to ON and I put the thankyou page in there.

After the purchase, it goes to the thankyou page, but the `$_REQUEST['tx']` for the paypal transaction ID is not working and the `notify_url` **NEVER** gets called.

I searched online and saw that lots of people seem to have trouble with that, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: File which PayPal hit in `notify_url` is on localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

notify_url is used to Instant Payment Notification and the url should always be a live URL.

To get the tx ID, you need to

-Auto Return is set to ON
-Valid Return URL
-Payment Data Transfer is set to ON

and in your "http://www.bewolfclothing.com/thankyou.php"

`$tx_id = $_GET['tx'];` //gives you tx id